# Convert this curl -F cmdline to python with request

Tags: python, curl

I try to do this:

```
curl -X POST -F file=@'infile.jpg' --output outfile.jpg 'http://pury.fi/censor?type=pixel&classes=ftite,fgene,fgenc'
```

form this site: https://pury.fi/site/api

in python to automate it as program and give it a UI.

Now ... There is the problem. How can I do this request in python?
I tried it like this:

```
    import requests

params = (
    ('type', 'pixel'),
    ('classes', 'ftite,fgene,fgenc'),
)

files = {
    'file': open('infile.jpg', 'rb'),
}

response = requests.post('http://pury.fi/censor', params=params, files=files)

with open('outfile.jpg', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(response.content)
```

and got a corrupted file. So can someone please help me?

Comment: I tried this and it worked, can you check what is the content of response.content?

Comment: @LorenzoBonetti The output is a "outfile.jpg", but it's corrupted. Or what do you mean?

Comment: I mean if you checked on the content if it is not empty, because i tried the same code writing the content and in my case it is a valid image

Comment: A corrupted file is more than "got nothing". Perhaps your question should be updated?

Comment: @9769953 That's true.

Comment: Superfluous `-X POST` detected.

Comment: @DanielStenberg ?

Comment: If I assume you use a *nix terminal: could you do `file outfile.jpg` and let us know what it reports?